# How to create a pair of header detail in crystal report?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

```
--Header1
--Detail1

--Header2
--Deatil2
```

How to Print two consecutive header... detail.. header.. detail in Single crystal report page.

Comment: You mean they have different data sources? Maybe you could use two subreports. But you should tell more details if you want more help.

Comment: Yes.. i have 2 SP both given different data. Lets say 1st SP give n no of data 2nd given m no of data. Now crystal report is divided into 5 section. But in section 2 is use for header. In section 3 Detail n no of record is display. But i have one more SP that is SP2 has given m no of record. So i want to print that data and also i want to give header to data display from SP2. In above code header1 and detail 1 is my 1st table.. on same report page i want to print another table that is header2 ane detail 2 table @heringer

Comment: Very confusing. Why cant you have your header and detail both in the subreport. and for each section have one sub report.